# Getting Appstore connect operation Error ITMS-90208 as I'm uploading iPhone build to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, deployment, app-store-connect

I have already sent build 5 times on App Store to on Testflight, everything worked fine, but for the sixth time as I'm uploading archived build to App Store it's giving me an error `ITMS-90208`. I have searched solution on StackOverflow from existing questions, but my issue is not resolved, applied all possible suggested things like #change minimumOsVersion in Flutter info.plist but all in vain. I have attached error [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5446I.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I already had the same Error, since xcode 13, you need to have a administartor Account on Apple Developer for send ipa to appstoreconnect. If you don't have a admin account you can download Xcode 12 and send your archive from xcode 12's organizer

Comment: Do you have any references about need to have a administartor Account on Apple Developer for send ipa to appstoreconnect?